# Auto-Start MySQL on OSX 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: mysql, macos, osx-yosemite, autostart

I have installed MySQL using homebrew (`brew install mysql`) to work with my Rails application. Upon completion, I got a fairly detailed setup guide to configure the MySQL server, however it was missing information on how to configure MySQL to start following boot.

To use MySQL, I must manually execute the following at the OSX Terminal:

- `cd . ; /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.25/bin/mysqld_safe &`

Using the instructions from this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26476391/how-to-auto-load-mysql-on-startup-on-osx-yosemite), I created an almost identical file, replacing the installation path with mine, but that didn't work as MySQL wasn't running after rebooting. I also noticed that I was missing the `mysqld_safe` file as can be seen in those instructions. I assumed those instructions wouldn't work for me as the OP there upgraded while I was on a new machine / OS installation.

Part of the instructions I got following installation stated:

> To start mysqld at boot time you have to copy
>   support-files/mysql.server to the right place for your system.

I have found **mysql.server** at `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.25/support-files` and I can also use that to start, stop and check the status of MySQL by running `/path/to/file/mysql.server` with the required function. However I don't know where the "right place" is on my system like the instructions put it.

--
How can I auto-start MySQL on my Mac running 10.10 after installing MySQL with brew? Is there a file similar to `rc.local` (on Linux) where I can put the startup command? Any help with this one?

-- **UPDATE** -- 
I found *mysqld_safe* at `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.25/bin/mysqld_safe` and after creating a new .plist file as explained in the [MySQL Launch Daemon](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/osx-installation-launchd.html) tutorial with --user set as `mysql` and also tried with `_mysql`, it still doesn't start MySQL following boot.

/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.mysql.mysqld</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
    <string>/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.25/bin/mysqld_safe</string>
    <string>--user=mysql</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

I should note that either of the following commands start MySQL following boot:

- `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.25/bin/mysqld_safe &`
- `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.25/support-files/mysql.server start`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I did - **brew info mysql**, it mentioned that I can use the following command to auto-start mysql on boot -

**ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mysql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents**

I did and the mysql has been auto-starting on boot on my OS X 10.10.3 Yosemite

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I also manually updated the `homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist` file with the correct location to `mysqld_safe`, leaving the WorkingDirectory & datadir as `/usr/local/var/mysql` (where the database files are stored). 
-- Can you share information about your setup, the location of MySQL (mysqld_safe) and the content of your MySQL launchd file at ~/Library/LaunchAgents ?

Comment: @n3rve Here is the relevant stuff (mysqld, datadir and working directory) from my /usr/local/opt/mysql/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist 
` <string>/usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe</string>`
`  <string>--datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql</string>`
  `<key>WorkingDirectory</key>
  <string>/usr/local/var/mysql</string> `.  Mysql launch file in `~/Library/LaunchAgents homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist` is a sym link to `/usr/local/opt/mysql/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist`. Pl. note that I have not made any update to the setup/files after `brew install mysql`. Just did as mentioned above and suggested by brew info.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `~/Library/LaunchAgents` are only started on login, not boot.

Answer (score 1):

From the, `brew info mysql` documentation, it says:

*To have launchd start mysql now and restart at login:*

```
brew services start mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had ever read the brew manual, you would probably know that. Tap `brew services`, you'll see "Integrates Homebrew formulae with OS X's launchctl manager. Services can be added to either /Library/LaunchDaemons or ~/Library/LaunchAgents. Basically, items in /Library/LaunchDaemons are started at boot, while those in ~/Library/LaunchAgent are started at login. When started with sudo, it operates on
/Library/LaunchDaemons; otherwise,it operates on ~/Library/LaunchAgents". Hope this maybe help.