# MySQL will not run on OSX El capitan for any reason whatsoever

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew, osx-elcapitan

First of all let me start by saying that I have read and tried all approaches that I found on the web and stack overflow.

What I get when I try to run

```
mysql.server start
```

or

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

is

```
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/hostname.local.pid).
```

What I get when I try to run:

```
mysql
```

is

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I also tried:

1. `sudo mysqld_safe &`
2. Clicking the mysql start button on system preferences.
3. Restart the computer
4. Reinstall mysql
5. Install older version of mysql
6. `killall` and then try to run mysql
7. `sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/mysql/`
8. `sudo chown -R mysql /var/lib/mysql/
9. `rm /usr/local/var/mysql/localhost.err`
10. `sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe start`
11. tried everything here: [How to auto-load MySQL on startup on OS X Yosemite / El Capitan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26476391/how-to-auto-load-mysql-on-startup-on-os-x-yosemite-el-capitan?rq=1)

I am out of ideas, I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to actually make it work:

```
killall -u username
brew remove mysql
brew cleanup
sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
sudo rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/My*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
sudo rm -rf /private/var/db/receipts/*mysql*
```

*Restart the computer

```
brew doctor and fix any errors
brew update
brew install mysql
unset TMPDIR
mysql_install_db --verbose --user=`whoami` --basedir="$(brew --prefix mysql)" --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp
mysql.server start
```