# Django - default port 0 instead of 3306 - Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, docker

I am trying to run my Django server but I get error `(2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)")`. I have found information in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26344795/cannot-connect-to-mysql-workbench-on-mac-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-127) that the problem can by caused by MySQL port. I had checked it using `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';` and I got value `0`. It seems to me that it may be a reason. I have checked in `my.cnf` default port but everything seems to look good `port       = 3306`. I wonder what should I do now? Thanks in advance.

**SOLUTION:**
I commented line `skip-networking` in `my.cnf` file.

Comment: Can you connect to MySQL through the command line?

Comment: `mysql -u <whatever> -p  -h 127.0.0.1`

Comment: No, I can't - mysql -u sth -p -h 127.0.0.1 - Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)

Comment: If that doesn't work, and `mysql -u <whatever> -p -h localhost` *DOES* work, then your MySQL server is not configured to listen to a IP address.

Comment: So how can I change it?

Comment: Have you checked the `bind-address` setting?

Comment: I was looking for `bind-address` but it doesn't exist in `my.cnf`

Comment: You need to add much more information to your question. How and where is MySQL running? How is Docker involved here? What commands are you using to start / stop your MySQL database server? What commands are you using to start your application?

Comment: I solved my problem, post updated. Thanks for support.

Answer (score -1):

Add `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` to your my.cnf under `[mysqld]`. Then restart the MySQL server. That will let it listen to the local IP address.

`bind-address = 0.0.0.0` will let it listen to all IP addresses (not recommended for production, but useful for debugging).

Comment: Can I add `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` at the end of the file? How can I restart MySQL?

Comment: I believe `XAMPP` has a control panel which would let you restart MySQL.
Put it under `[mysqld]`.

Comment: I have done everything as you have written and `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT'` still returns `0` and server - (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)").

Comment: Can you use `localhost` as a setting in Django and see what happens there?